# C difference between *(unsigned char *)s1 and (unsigned char)*s1

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, casting

I have an assignment to re-write some popular C function which are available in the libc.

I'm writing `strcmp` and when I was done and happy with it I went to check the one in the libc.

This is mine :

```
int     ft_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1 && *s1 == *s2)
    {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return ((unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2);
}
```

And this is the one in the libc (https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c) :

```
int
strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    for ( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++)
    if (*s1 == '\0')
        return 0;
    return ((*(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2) ? -1 : +1); // HERE ! Why *(unsigned char *) :/ ?
}
```

I don't understand why that `*(unsigned char *)s1` works, I thought it wouldn't, but it really seems to !

And then I found this implementation in another libc (https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strcmp.c;h=a4645638eb685e479b89a5e3912076329cc27773;hb=HEAD)

```
int
strcmp (p1, p2)
  const char *p1;
  const char *p2;
{
    const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *) p1;
    const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *) p2;
    unsigned char c1, c2; 
    do
    {
       c1 = (unsigned char) *s1++;
       c2 = (unsigned char) *s2++;
       if (c1 == '\0')
           return c1 - c2;
     }
     while (c1 == c2); 
     return c1 - c2;
}
```

Whis is also weird but for other reasons, and this one use what I thought was right `(const unsigned char *) p1`

Comment: "I thought it wouldn't" - why wouldn't it?

Comment: why add another * then ? I mean what's the point of these 2 stars ?

Comment: um what? So why did you think that construct wouldn't work? The first star is the `*` operator that dereferences the pointer. The second star (inside the typecast) is the pointer qualifier.

Comment: Why is there 2 * in `*(unsigned char *)s1`

Comment: Just explained that...

Comment: aaaahh I got it, so we take the `char *` then cast it to `unsigned char *` and then dereference it right ? But then why not just derefence it first and cast the value ?

Comment: In this context, there's no difference, but if the pointer wasn't a `char *`, but e. g. if the code would alias an `int *`, then there would.

Comment: That's what I was really asking thanks ! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `(unsigned char)*s1` and `*(unsigned char*)s1` is in how data is loaded from the position that `s1` points to:

- `(unsigned char)*s1` reads a value of the type `s1` points to, then converts that value to an `unsigned char`. This variant cannot invoke undefined behaviour.

  If `s1` were a `double*`, a `double` would be read (that is, 8 bytes will be loaded from memory), and its value would be converted to an `unsigned char`
- `*(unsigned char*)s1` first changes what the pointer is supposed to point to, then reads the first byte at the location `s1` points at. Under certain conditions, this is undefined behaviour with the newer standards, your case does not invoke undefined behaviour, though.

  If `s1` were a `double*` again, the resulting code will load the bit pattern in the first byte in which the double is stored (that is, only one byte will be loaded). This will be something entirely different then the logical value of the double.

---

#### Asside

Concerning the possibility of undefined behaviour, the rules are roughly as follows:

- Casting a pointer to something that is "close enough" is fine. This includes casts changing constness and signedness.
- Casts to `char*` types are a special case, they never invoke undefined behaviour. (Thanks to Jens Gustedt for pointing this out.)

So we have the following cases:

- Casting an `int*` to a `const unsigned int*` is fine.
- Casting an `int*` to a `char*` is fine.
- Casting a `double*` to an `uint64*` to analyse the bit pattern of the double is undefined behaviour, and allows your compiler to insert code formatting your harddrive.

Comment: partially wrong answer, though. Casting any data pointer to `unsigned char*` is perfectly fine. The standard guarantees that this will always work. `unsigned char` has the minimal alignment requirements and cannot have trap representations. Interpreting a byte as a byte is always possible.

Comment: @JensGustedt But doesn't casting a `double*` to an `unsigned char*` violate strict aliasing rules? I know that reinterpreting pointer casts were valid C once, but I had the impression that the strict aliasing rules in the newer standards made such reinterpretations virtually impossible without invoking UB.

Comment: @cmaster, no, character types are exempted from these aliasing rules and have always been.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thank you, for correcting me. You were right, and I have modified the answer now to reflect my increased knowledge. I hope, you like it better now :-)

Answer (score 3):

`(unsigned char *)s1` typecasts s1 from a `const char *s1` to a `(unsigned char *)s1` and `*(unsigned char *)s1` dereferences it to get the value.

Comment: So it's not the same thing right ? It should'nt behave exactly the same

Comment: Perhaps `char` is signed, that's why it's being typecast to `unsigned`.

Comment: what's bothering me is the second `*` in `(*(unsigned char *)s1`

Comment: @ItsASecret Once again, for the last time. **That belongs to the type and it is the pointer qualifier.**

Comment: `(unsigned char *)s1` == the address of `s1` and `*(unsigned char *)s1` == the value of the `unsigned char` that `s1` is pointing to.

Comment: For your 2nd example: it casts and then dereferences. So the 2nd example is your 1st example with an additional dereferencing, as done by the outer `*`.

Comment: @alk Where is my mistake?

Comment: No mistake, just unclear speach. (from a didactical point of view ... :) I just tried to add more clarity to your answer.

Comment: Ok, there is a "mistake" .. this `*1`, which seems to be a typo.

Comment: @alk Pointers and typecasting are tricky, so confusion (in explaining and understanding) is to be expected!

Comment: So take your time, to find your thoughts and words. And: Always read twice what you wrote .. ;-)

Comment: @alk You're right, but sometimes my mind is similar to a steel trap… nothing in and nothing out.

Answer (score 3):

you take a `char*` and dereference it to a `char` and then cast it to an `unsigned char`

the one you don't think would work simply casts the pointer to an `unsigned char*` first, then when it dereferences it's an `unsigned char`.

in this case because it's just going from a `char` to `unsigned char`, there's basically no difference.

if however the original pointer was to an `int` or something,  yours would get an `int` and cast it to `unsigned char`.  the other one would get the first byte of an `int` and return it as an `unsigned char`

Comment: Thank you much clearer, sorry @H2CO3 maybe it's really easy stuff for you but that wasn't clear!

Comment: @ItsASecret: Its logical, thats for sure, but it isn't easy as human is not used to logic, ... - per definition. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `char` and `unsigned char` are similar enough that they can be interpreted in the same way.

Long answer: The C standard is specific enough that it guarantees that both `char` and `unsigned char` will have a size of 1 byte, and store their "value bits" in the same format. So up to values of 127, the behavior of this function is strictly defined.

It only gets messy when you get to the sign bit. The C standard allows the sign bit to represent one's complement, two's complement, or signed magnitude, depending on the implementation. So on a platform using two's complement (which is the most common by far), -1 would be represented as `11111111`, and would equal 255 when interpreted as an `unsigned char`. But using signed magnitude, it would be represented as `10000001` and equal 129 when interpreted as an `unsigned char`.

In the latter case, this is DIFFERENT than what would get by explicitly casting to `unsigned char` (the `(unsigned char) s1++` example):

> if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.

So the C standard guarantees that if you explicitly cast `-1` to an `unsigned char`, the value `256` will be added, making the result of the cast `255`. So if you were on a platform using signed magnitude:

```
    char c = -1;
    unsigned char u1 = (unsigned char)c; // this results in 255
    unsigned char u2 = *(unsigned char *)&c; // this results in 129!
```

I imagine that these discrepancies are so uncommon that no one notices them though. C implementations that don't use 2's complement are few and far between.